# MySQL: Get products tha only have disabled categories

Tags: mysql

- A product can have multiple categories associated via the pivot table products_categories.
- The categories can be enabled (status = 1) or disabled (status = 0).
- The id column in the categories table is unique / auto_increment.

I need to find products that ONLY have disabled categories.

So if a product belongs to two categories, one with status = 0 and one with status = 1 that products should not be part of my result.

Obviously this will not work:

```
SELECT
    products.id
FROM
    products
JOIN
    products_categories
ON
    products.id = products_categories.product_id
JOIN
    categories
ON
    products_categories.category_id = categories.id
WHERE
    categories.status = 0
;
```

Here is my tables:

```
products
id (AUTO_INCREMENT)

products_categories
product_id  (INT)
category_id (INT)

categories
id     (AUTO_INCREMENT)
status (INT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only the product ids then you can use only the tables `products_categories` and `categories`.

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT pc.product_id
FROM products_categories pc 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM categories c
  WHERE c.id = pc.category_id AND c.status = 1
);
```

or, with aggregation:

```
SELECT pc.product_id
FROM products_categories pc INNER JOIN categories c
ON c.id = pc.category_id
GROUP BY pc.product_id
HAVING MAX(c.status) = 0;
```

Comment: I'd be cautious of the logic failing if a status lower than `0` got introduced. To that end I'd use `<> 0` in the `EXISTS` variant, and test both `MIN()` and `MAX()` for the aggregation variant.

Comment: @MatBailie *The categories can be enabled (status = 1) or disabled (status = 0)* there is no reason to make complex conditions for such a simple requirement.

Comment: I specifically refer to robustness against future change, by making the logic more explicit and thus resilient to change. I also don't see how `<> 0` can ever be construed as 'complex'...

Answer (score 1):

In this case `GROUP BY products.id` with `HAVING MIN(status) = '0' AND MAX(status) = '0'` should do the trick.

```
SELECT products.id
FROM products
JOIN products_categories ON products.id = products_categories.product_id
JOIN categories ON products_categories.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY products.id
HAVING MIN(status) = '0' AND MAX(status) = '0';
```

[In this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=933379b3d93cd19be4532f4c54a7c691) you can find a simple demo.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the `id` in the categories table is unique / auto increment. So product with id = 1 could have two categories (id 1 and2 ) attached via the pivot table.